# XDocument does not load Xml string properly

Tags: c#, xml, linq-to-xml

I'm trying to do the following: load an Xml string into a `XDocument` object, but when I try to access elements through `Descendants` method it return nothing when I tried to see the value of inner elements in Visual Studio it does not recognize it as Xml so what is the problem here?

```
string xml = @"<ArrayOfKeyValueOfstringint xmlns=""http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/Arrays"" xmlns:i=""http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"">
  <KeyValueOfstringint>
    <Key>crscmprsn_ttlprt1</Key>
    <Value>1</Value>
  </KeyValueOfstringint>
  <KeyValueOfstringint>
    <Key>ptntmntrfrm_ttlprt1</Key>
    <Value>1</Value>
  </KeyValueOfstringint>
</ArrayOfKeyValueOfstringint>";

var xdoc = XDocument.Parse(xml);
IEnumerable<XElement> elements = xdoc.Descendants("KeyValueOfstringint");

var lst = new List<KeyValuePair<string,int>>();

foreach (var item in elements)
{
    var k = item.Element("Key").Value;
    int v = int.Parse(item.Element("Value").Value);
    var kvp = new KeyValuePair<string,int>(k,v);
    lst.Add(kvp);
}
```

[image: debugger visualizer]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to specify namespace to get your elements:

```
var ns = "http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/Arrays";

var elements = xdoc.Descendants(ns + "KeyValueOfstringint");
```

For more information about xml namespaces take a look at: [`Working with XML Namespaces`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb387093.aspx)